# Show/Hide div when checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, show-hide

I need to make additional content appear when a user selects a checkbox. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Checkbox</title>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){
if(this.checked)
$('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
else
$('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');

});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
Add another director <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would really appreciate some help, good knowledge of HTML5, CSS3 but very basic JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library on that page? I can't see something like `<script type="text/javascript" src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>` in the example code.

Comment: And what is your problem exactly?

Comment: included the library, simply not working? the content isnt hiding when the checkbox is selected

Comment: @user2890036 You want it to hide when it's selected? Then you have to do !this.checked

Comment: solved now sorry for confusion. Solved by @Anton easily enough can't have been that misleading. simple code fix but as I stated - I have little Javascript knowledge.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing jQuery in your head you must include it.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

Your code works [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3WEVr/)

**Update according to new info**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked) 
        //  ^
           $('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
        else 
            $('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3WEVr/6/)

You can also just use .fadeToggle()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox1').change(function () {
      $('#autoUpdate').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer - it now works other than i would like it to be hidden to start with, any ideas how i would go about this. thanks again.

Comment: you can use css for that, `#autoUpdate{display:none}` @user2890036 Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3WEVr/8/

Comment: Thanks! all working as required.

Answer (score 3):

first in head include [jquery](http://www.jquery.com/)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox1').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    $('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
    else
    $('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');

    });
    });
</script>
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/3WEVr/5/)**

reference [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

Plese replace your code with below it will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Checkbox</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
$('#checkbox1').change(function(){
if(this.is(":checked") == true)
$('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
else
$('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');

});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
    Add another director <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"/>
<div id="autoUpdate" class="autoUpdate">
content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to wrap this with jQuery $() so $(this).is(':checked')