# How to display the radio buttons when a check box is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The display must be in a grid view without any misalignment. Here are the Screen Shots

[image: Shot1]

[image: Shot2]

the code used is HTML and Javascript. How to format those radio buttons accordingly in CSS & HTML.

Comment: can you share your html/css

Comment: maybe create a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) ...

Comment: hope this link will help you...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447591/show-hide-div-when-checkbox-selected

Comment: I got the functionality but I am not able to move my radio buttons just below the checkbox selected here is the code.

I am formatting a checkbox accordingly in CSS but after checking another check box its getting disturbed.


I'll edit the post with the code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DEwH2/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#myCheckbox").change( function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $('#options-radio').css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

I am sure in this way, issue will be resolved

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRFL4/) for the sample

Comment: I need the radio buttons to be at the position underneath the checkboxes.

Comment: You can set whatever position of radio button div. and make that hide. 

and then above code of ischecked  then show that div will be fine.

Comment: How can I do that.
I want to move that radio button just below the Audiometry checkbox in CSS.
As their is another checkbox Electrocardiogram.

When each and every checkbox is checked it must be displayed just below that checked checkbox.