# JavaScript Show/Hide DIV

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a form where the user choose if he/she is `SINGLE CITIZENSHIP` **OR** `DUAL CITIZENSHIP`.
If the user chooses `SINGLE CITIZENSHIP` the **hidden** `div` will **not show** up and if the user chooses `DUAL CITIZENSHIP` the **hidden** `div` will **show below**.

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Filipino</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">Dual Citizenship</label>
</div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">By birth</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">By Naturalize</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Minimum effort please...

Comment: Unable to see `SINGLE CITIZENSHIP` in your HTML as well as please post your code efforts too (in the question itself).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show/hide 'div' using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070101/show-hide-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Sorry. If the user used *FILIPINO* <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Filipino</label>

Comment: perhaps you can try `<?php if(condition): ?> here <?php endif; ?> `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `change()` event of `jQuery` and show-hide div.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inlineCheckbox2').change(function () {
        if (!this.checked)
           $('#hidden').fadeOut('slow');
        else 
            $('#hidden').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
#hidden{
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="checkbox"
      id="inlineCheckbox1"
      value="option1"
    />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Filipino</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input
      class="form-check-input"
      type="checkbox"
      id="inlineCheckbox2"
      value="option2"
    />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2"
      >Dual Citizenship</label
    >
  </div>
</div>

<div id="hidden">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        id="inlineCheckbox1"
        value="option1"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">By birth</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input
        class="form-check-input"
        type="checkbox"
        id="inlineCheckbox2"
        value="option2"
      />
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2"
        >By Naturalize</label
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19447642/10971575

Comment: @kiinken  what happened if someone clicked `Dual Citizenship` and then clicked on `single citizenship`? this code will not worked

Comment: @kiinken  check this:- https://jsfiddle.net/e1yLopjz/1/   (click on second checkbox and then click on first checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

```
let valeInpOne = document.getElementById('inlineCheckbox1'); 
let valeInpTwo = document.getElementById('inlineCheckbox2').value; 
let ele = document.getElementById("hidden");

if(valeInpOne == 'option1'){ ele.hidden = true }else if(valeInpTwo == 'option2'){ ele.hidden = false }
```